# Subscripts and superscripts "-" or "+" with ggplot2 axis labels? (ionic chemical notation)

Tags: r, ggplot2, notation

I got this plot using the code below

[image]

In my plot, I want the NO3 to have negative sign"-" as superscript like below

[image]

In the label of x axis, I couldn't use negative sign only as a superscript to NO3 so I had to use -1 as shown below

```
x <- seq(0,2*pi,0.1)
y <- sin(x)

df <- data.frame(x, y)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))+
geom_point(size=4)+
labs(x=expression(Production~rate~" "~mu~moles~NO[3]^{-1}-N~Kg^{-1}),
     y=expression(Concentration~mg~L^{-1}))
```

Any suggestions on how to change the label to have a negative sign only without 1?

Comment: Just use a string value rather than a numeric one: `NO[3]^{"-"}`

Comment: And there's yet another strategy. Use an empty character after a (unary) minus. Has the advantage that all the minuses then look alike: `NO[3]^{-""}

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try quoting the minus sign after the superscript operator:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))+
geom_point(size=4)+
labs(x=expression(Production~rate~" "~mu~moles~NO[3]^{"-"}-N~Kg^{-1}),
     y=expression(Concentration~mg~L^{-1})) +
theme(legend.title = element_text(size=12, face="bold"),
      legend.text=element_text(size=12),
      axis.text=element_text(size=12),
      axis.title = element_text(color="black", face="bold", size=18))
```

I think it looks more scientifically accurate to use the `%.%` operator between units:

```
+ labs(x=expression(Production~rate~" "~mu~moles~NO[3]^{textstyle("-")}-N %.% Kg^{-1}),
     y=expression(Concentration~mg~L^{-1})) +
```

`textstyle` should keep the superscript-ed text from being reduced in size. I'm also not sure why you have a `" "` between two tildes. You can string a whole bunch of tildes together to increase "spaces":

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))+
geom_point(size=4)+
labs(x=expression(Production~rate~~~~~~~~~~~~mu~moles~NO[3]^{textstyle("-")}-N %.% Kg^{-1}),
     y=expression(Concentration~mg~L^{-1})) +
theme(legend.title = element_text(size=12, face="bold"),
      legend.text=element_text(size=12),
      axis.text=element_text(size=12),
      axis.title = element_text(color="black", face="bold", size=18))
```

[image]

And a bonus plotmath tip: Quoting numbers is a way to get around the documented difficulty in producing italicized digits with plotmath. (Using `italic(123)` does not succeed, ... but `italic("123")` does.)

Comment: How would this work if you wanted to have the units contained within parentheses? Such as "Concentration (mg L^-1)" rather than "Concentration mg L^-1"

Comment: Parentheses could be inside text-quotes so: `expression(Concentration~"("*mg~L^{-1}*")")`. seems less elegant. Better I think is `expression(Concentration~(mg%.%L^{-1}) )`. Note that `*` is used when no space is desired between non-plotmath items. As a matter of style I would prefer using a 'cdot' between unit designators: `expression(Concentration~(mg%.%L^{-1}))`

Comment: I ended up using ```labs(y=expression(paste("Concentration (mg ", L^-1,")")))```